# Bootstrap's Pagination in reactjs - Data coming from MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, reactjs, pagination

Am trying to make a pagination in reactjs application. Please find the code below.
Finally am not able to render the list. Its giving blank list. could someone help me out to figure out the error here.?
Please find the complete code.

```
    return (
  <table className="table table-hover" >
    <thead >
      <tr>
        <th>Order Number</th>
        <th>Customer Name</th>
        <th>Created By</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <SearchResultsList items={this.props.results} open={this.props.open} />
  </table>
);
    }
    }
class SearchResultsList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }
  render() {
    const per_page = 10;
    const pages = Math.ceil(this.props.items.length / per_page);
    const current_page = 1;
    const start_offset = (current_page - 1) * per_page;
    let start_count = 0;
    return (
      <tbody>
        {
          this.props.items.sort(
            (a, b) => moment(b.order_date) - moment(a.order_date) || b.order_number -
              a.order_number)
            .map((item, index) => {
              if (index >= start_offset && start_count < per_page) {
                start_count++;
                <SearchResultsItem key={item.id} item={item} open={this.props.open} />
              }
            })
        }
      </tbody>
    );
    <Pagination
      ClassName="items-pagination pull-right"
      bsSize="medium"
      maxButton={10}
      first last next prev boundaryLinks
      item={pages}
      activePage={current_page} />
  }
    class SearchResultsItem extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
    this.state = {};
  }
  handleInputChange(e) {
    const target = e.target;
    const name = target.name;
    const value = target.type === 'checkbox' ? target.checked : target.value;
    this.setState({ [name]: value });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <tr style={{ fontsize: '10', cursor: 'pointer' }}
    <td>{this.props.item.order_number}</td>
      <td>{this.props.item.customer_name}</td>
      <td>{this.props.item.buyer_name}</td>
    </tr >
    );
  }
}
```

Please find the demo data below. Data coming from mongodb as JSON objects.

```
{ 
"_id" : "658ecv57b-3853-46f4-af6c-cb1ca111137f", 
"order_number" : "1000123", 
"customer_name" : "rahul", 
"buyer_name" : "rahul", 
}
{ 
"_id" : "1258ecv57b-3853-46f4-af6c-cb1ca111137f", 
"order_number" : "1000123", 
"customer_name" : "Bruce", 
"buyer_name" : "Bruce", 
}
{ 
"_id" : "658ecv57b-3853-46f4-af6c-cb1ca1111312f", 
"order_number" : "1000123", 
"customer_name" : "mike", 
"buyer_name" : "mike", 
}
{ 
"_id" : "658ecv57b-3853-46f4-af6c-cb112111137f", 
"order_number" : "1000123", 
"customer_name" : "linda", 
"buyer_name" : "linda", 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have missed the `return` in your `map` function in `SearchResultsList`.

```
this.props.items.sort(
          (a, b) => moment(b.order_date) - moment(a.order_date) || b.order_number - a.order_number)
.map((item, index) => {
               if (index >= start_offset && start_count < per_page ){
                    start_count++;
                    return <SearchResultsItem key={ item.id } item={ item } 
                           open={ this.props.open } />;
               }
         }
```

Comment: But you need to  return `<SearchResultsItem key={ item.id } item={ item }                     open={ this.props.open } />;` from your `.map` function, otherwise `.map` will return void.

Comment: Your Pagination Nav Bar is not in the return statement.

Comment: i have updated my code and included Pagination Nav Bar inside return statement. But dont know how to move to next - next page. Right now am able to show only 10 records out of 50 records.   I have opened another question on the same. Please find the url : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46924112/reactjs-pagination-unable-to-paginate-the-data