# reactjs pagination with json data from mongodb

Tags: mongodb, reactjs, pagination

Am trying to implement pagination in reactjs with JSON data from mongodb. But pages is not navigating as per the records available.

Below points are working :

Pagination buttons has been available.
Am able to click and change the button from the pagination navbar.

Below point are not working :

Tables records are not changing as the the pagination navbar button click.

Please find the code below.

```
class SearchResults extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {  };
this.handlePageChange=this.handlePageChange.bind(this);
}

getNumPages(currentPage) {
{ this.handlePageChange } 
this.setState({ per_page: this.props.results , currentPage: currentPage + 1 , previousPage: currentPage - 1  } );
}

handlePageChange(page, evt) {
const currentPage = this.state.currentPage || 1;
const numPages = this.getNumPages();
const pageLinks = [];
if (currentPage > 1) {
if (currentPage > 2) {
pageLinks.push(1);
pageLinks.push(' ');
}
pageLinks.push(currentPage - 1);
pageLinks.push(' ');
}
for (let i = 1; i <= numPages; i++) {
const page = i;
pageLinks.push(page);
}
if (currentPage < numPages) {
pageLinks.push(' ');
pageLinks.push(currentPage + 1);
if (currentPage < numPages - 1) {
pageLinks.push(' ');
pageLinks.push(numPages);
}
}
this.setState({ currentPage: currentPage + 1  } );
this.setState({ previousPage: currentPage - 1  } );
}

render() {
const per_page = "10";
const paginationData = this.props.results;
let numPages = Math.ceil(paginationData.length / per_page);
if (paginationData.length % per_page > 0) {
numPages++;
}
return (
<div className="panel panel-primary">
<div className="panel-heading">ORDERS LIST</div>
<table className="table table-hover" }} >
<thead >
<tr>
<th>Customer Name</th>
<th>Assignee</th>
<th>Status</th>
<th>Creation Date </th>
</tr>
</thead>
<SearchResultsList items={ this.props.results } open={ this.props.open } />
</table>

<Pagination id="content" className="users-pagination pull-right" bsSize="medium" 
first last  next  prev  boundaryLinks items={numPages} 
activePage={ this.state.currentPage } onSelect={ this.handlePageChange } />
</div>
);
}
}

class SearchResultsList extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = { };
}

render() {
const per_page=10;
let currentPage=8;
let start_count =0;
return (<tbody>{ this.props.items
.sort((a, b) => moment(b.order_date) - moment(a.order_date) || b.order_number - a.order_number)
.map((item, index) => <SearchResultsItem key={ item.id } item={ item } open={ this.props.open }  /> 
) 
}</tbody>);
}
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reactjs Pagination - unable to paginate the data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46924112/reactjs-pagination-unable-to-paginate-the-data)

Comment: yes, but i have modified the code., almost near to the solution now. This approach is better than my previous approach.. Could you please help me out..?

Comment: you are missing `if (index >= start_offset && start_count < per_page)`  this line and not passed values to the `SearchResultsList`

Comment: yes., your are correct i have to pass index value to the SearchResultsList. but its not (if (index >= start_offset && start_count < per_page) ) . Am unsure what to pass to render it...

Comment: Only rendering is not happening., apart from that, all functions are working fine.

Comment: There are lots of issues in code, man.

Comment: can i place the same code in jfiddle..??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it got working for me. Please find Pagination working code.

```
class SearchResults extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {  };
this.handlePageChange=this.handlePageChange.bind(this);
}

getNumPages(currentPage) {
{ this.handlePageChange } 
this.setState({ per_page: this.props.results , currentPage: currentPage + 1 , previousPage: currentPage - 1  } );
}

handlePageChange(page, evt) {
const currentPage = this.state.currentPage || 1;
const numPages = this.getNumPages();
const pageLinks = [];
if (currentPage > 1) {
if (currentPage > 2) {
pageLinks.push(1);
pageLinks.push(' ');
}
pageLinks.push(currentPage - 1);
pageLinks.push(' ');
}
for (let i = 1; i <= numPages; i++) {
const page = i;
pageLinks.push(page);
}
if (currentPage < numPages) {
pageLinks.push(' ');
pageLinks.push(currentPage + 1);
if (currentPage < numPages - 1) {
pageLinks.push(' ');
pageLinks.push(numPages);
}
}
this.setState({ currentPage: currentPage + 1  } );
this.setState({ previousPage: currentPage - 1  } );
}

render() {
    const per_page = "10";
const paginationData = this.props.results;
let numPages = Math.ceil(paginationData.length / per_page);
if (paginationData.length % per_page > 0) {
numPages++;
}
return (
<div className="panel panel-primary">
<div className="panel-heading">ORDERS LIST</div>
<table className="table table-hover" }} >
<thead >
<tr>
<th>Customer Name</th>
<th>Assignee</th>
<th>Status</th>
<th>Creation Date </th>
</tr>
</thead>
<SearchResultsList items={ this.props.results } open={ this.props.open } current_Page={ this.state.currentPage }  />
</table>

<Pagination id="content" className="users-pagination pull-right" bsSize="medium" 
first last  next  prev  boundaryLinks items={numPages} 
activePage={ this.state.currentPage } onSelect={ this.handlePageChange } />
</div>
);
}
}

class SearchResultsList extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = { };
}

    render() {

const per_page=10;
const pages = Math.ceil(this.props.items.length / per_page);
const current_page = this.props.current_Page || 1 ;
const start_offset = (current_page - 1) * per_page;
let start_count =0;
return (<tbody>{ this.props.items
.sort((a, b) => moment(b.order_date) - moment(a.order_date) || b.order_number - a.order_number)
.map((item, index) => {
if (index >= start_offset && start_count < per_page) {
start_count++;
return <SearchResultsItem key={item.id} item={item} open={this.props.open} />;
}
})
}    
</tbody>
);
}
}
```